# GHC incompatibility installing haskell-src-exts via cabal

Tags: installation, ghc, cabal, agda, happy

I'm running into a compatibility problem trying to `cabal install agda` using GHC 7.8.3 and Cabal 1.16.0.2, on Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem appears to be with `haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1`, which Agda requires. Compiling that library runs into the following [well-known problem](http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-08-happy-alex-ghc-7.8.html) caused (I believe) by [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/)-generated code being incompatible with [a change to GHC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PrimBool) in version 7.8.

```
templates/GenericTemplate.hs:104:22:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                with actual type ‘Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#’
    In the expression:
      (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   a case alternative:
      (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
    In a case alternative:
        n | (n Happy_GHC_Exts.<# (0# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))
          -> (happyReduceArr Happy_Data_Array.! rule) i tk st
          where
              rule
                = (Happy_GHC_Exts.I#
                     ((Happy_GHC_Exts.negateInt#
                         ((n Happy_GHC_Exts.+# (1# :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#))))))
```

The [article mentioned above](http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-08-happy-alex-ghc-7.8.html) describes how to clean and rebuild a library that contains incompatible Happy-generated code. However, I couldn't make this work for haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1. In particular, trying

```
cabal unpack haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 
cd haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1
cabal clean
cabal install
```

runs into the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't reproduced the problem using Happy 1.19.4 (the above article says "Install the latest versions of alex and happy").

Comment: I installed happy-1.19.4 and alex-3.1.3, but still get the same problem.

Comment: FYI, I'm using cabal-install version 1.20.0.3 using version 1.20.0.1 of the Cabal library. Which is the output of the following commands: `cabal get haskell-src-exts`, `cd haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1/`, `cabal clean` and `cabal configure -v`?

Comment: I'm also using cpphs 1.18.5.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I upgraded to cabal 1.20.0.3. The output of `cabal configure -v` is [here](http://pastie.org/9443688). Now I get [these errors](http://pastie.org/9443699) at roughly the same point in the compilation; maybe they shed some light on my problem? (I've checked and I have cpphs, polyparse and text already installed.)

Comment: I didn't see any problems in the output of `cabal configure -v`. Which is the output of `cabal install -v`?

Comment: And which is the output of `ghc-pkg list`?

Comment: Here is [`cabal install -v`](http://pastie.org/9444997), and also [`ghc-pck list`](http://pastie.org/9444999).

Comment: Also wondered whether [this](http://pastie.org/9445018) may help.

Comment: Reinstall all the libraries using cabal 1.20.0.3 (see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9060).

Comment: Ok, that fixes my problem. Thanks. I had to do a `cabal install` of `text`, `polyparse` and `cpphs` (in that order), with options `--reinstall --force-reinstalls` (ignoring the warning). Feel free to summarise this in an answer. (If you do, please also mention the need to upgrade cabal, and include a link to the trac issue.)

Comment: It turned out that at least two other libraries (`hashtable` and `zlib`) were broken too and needed reinstalling. So in the end, safer simply to delete `~/.ghc` to force a rebuild of everything, as described in the trac issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Cabal 1.16.* is incompatible with GHC 7.8.3, so install a recent version of cabal-install (e.g. version 1.20.0.3), delete the directory associated to GHC 7.8.3 from ~/.ghc (e.g. x86_64-linux-7.8.3) and install everything again.

**Long answer**: See [GHC issue 9060](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9060).